# Expectation of Continuous variable.

Tags: probability-distributions

Given the probability density function

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{cx}{3}, &  0 \leq x < 3, \\
c, & 3 \leq x \leq 4, \\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I have found $c$ to be $0.4$ and $E(X)$ to be $2.6$. But I'm being asked to find $E(3X - 5)$ and I'm unsure of what to do.

Comment: Are you familiar with the phrase "linearity of expectation"? (i.e., the expectation is a linear operator: $\mathbb{E}[aX+b] = a\mathbb{E}[X]+b$ for any constants $a,b$)

Comment: use the definition of expectation, you dont need to know something more than this.

Answer (score -1):

$$\mathbf E(3\mathbf X-5)=3\mathbf E(\mathbf X)-5=3(2.4)-5=2.2$$